Why doesn't netcat print anything when listening in UDP mode when it can't reach the client even when the client can reach the server?
I'm using a fresh minimal Ubuntu server 24.04.1 LTS install.
I run these commands as root to set up networking and do some experiments:
apt install netcat-traditional

ip netns add ns1
ip netns add ns2

ip link add my_veth1 type veth peer name my_veth2

ip link set my_veth1 up netns ns1
ip link set my_veth2 up netns ns2

ip -n ns1 address add 1.2.3.4 dev my_veth1
ip -n ns1 route add 2.3.4.0/24 dev my_veth1

ip netns exec ns2 nc -u -l -p 8080

then I run this from another terminal:
ip netns exec ns1 nc -u 2.3.4.5 8080 <<< 'Hello world from network namespace ns1'

UDP is a connectionless protocol. If my understanding is correct this should mean that the netcat UDP server from network namespace ns2 should be able to print the message the client from ns1 sent regardless of whether the server can reach the client or not, so in theory I shouldn't have to configure a route in ns2 or an ip address in my_veth2. However, no message is being printed in the first terminal unless both the ip address and the routing table entry are configured. Why?

I tried adding the ip address 2.3.4.5 to my_veth2 but that didn't work.
I tried creating a new routing table entry in ns2 to redirect all traffic from 1.2.3.0/24 to my_veth2 but that didn't work either.
The message would only be printed when adding the ip address 2.3.4.5 to my_veth2 AND creating a new routing table entry in ns2 to redirect all traffic from 1.2.3.0/24 to my_veth2. Why is that?


EDIT: Disabling rp_filter doesn't seem to do the trick:
ip netns exec ns1 dd of=/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter <<< '0'
ip netns exec ns2 dd of=/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter <<< '0'
ip netns exec ns1 dd of=/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/my_veth1/rp_filter <<< '0'
ip netns exec ns2 dd of=/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/my_veth2/rp_filter <<< '0'


EDIT 2: Installing and running tcpdump I learned that there were some ARP requests being sent that weren't being responded:
$ ip netns exec ns1 tcpdump -l -i my_veth1
23:38:14.402259 ARP, Request who-has 2.3.4.5 tell 1.2.3.4, length 28
23:38:14.402259 ARP, Request who-has 2.3.4.5 tell 1.2.3.4, length 28
23:38:14.402259 ARP, Request who-has 2.3.4.5 tell 1.2.3.4, length 28
...


ns2 my_veth2 gives the same output

So I tried creating the ARP table entry manually...
ip -n ns1 neighbour add 2.3.4.5 dev my_veth1 lladdr $(ip netns exec ns2 cat /sys/class/net/my_veth2/address)

And now apparently the UDP packet is being sent
$ ip netns exec ns1 tcpdump -l -i my_veth1
00:24:15.164245 IP 1.2.3.4.36170 > 2.3.4.5.8080: UDP, length 39


ns2 my_veth2 gives the same output

However, the first terminal that has the UDP netcat server running still doesn't output anything. Why?

EDIT 3: After doing all of the above, I tried assigning an IP address to my_veth2:
ip -n ns2 address add 2.3.4.5 dev my_veth2

And now, when I send the UDP packet, I get this error in the terminal that is running netcat in listen mode:
no connection : Network is unreachable

Why? I mean, of course the network is unreachable, but that shouldn't stop the server from receiving and displaying UDP packets. In fact, that error is only displayed when it receives the UDP packet. So even if it knows that it can't answer, it should be able to receive and display the message, right?

"UDP" is short for "UDP/IP". Packets are routed at the Internet Protocol level. Without a route (on the client) from the client (Packet originator) to the server (netcat ...), the client doesn't know which interface to use, or where to send the packets. Yes, the client will use its default route, but will it be right?

"If my understanding is correct this should mean that the netcat UDP server from network namespace ns2 should be able to print the message the client from ns1 sent regardless of whether the server can reach the client or not" - You understanding of "connectionless" is wrong. In the context of UDP it only means that it does not establish an explicit connection with defined start and end like TCP does. There still needs to be a way to actually deliver the packets at the lower levels of the protocol stack (IP, ethernet, ...)

@waltinator But the client does have a route. I set it up when I run ip netns exec ns1 ip route add 2.3.4.0/24 dev my_veth1. Either I don't understand what you meant or you maybe didn't notice that I've set up that routing entry.

@SteffenUllrich There is a way to deliver the packet the client sends to the server. It's just that there isn't any way for the server to send a response back to the client. But in the UDP protocol the server shouldn't need to be able to reach the client to be able to print the message the client sends to the server, right? Shouldn't be enough if the client could reach the server, even if the server couldn't get back to the client?

@Adrian: at the UDP level yes. But there might be (security) mechanism at the underlying layer which block incoming packets if there is no matching outgoing route - like reverse path filtering. In this case the packets would not even reach the UDP stack

@SteffenUllrich I've tried turning rp_filter off, but it still doesn't work. What else could be the problem?

@Adrian: first make sure that the packets even arrive at the specific interface, using tcpdump or similar.

@SteffenUllrich I did. See EDIT 2.

You initially only create an IP address "IP1" on ns1 and a route to an imaginary (non-existing) IP address "IP2" on ns2.
Trying to even send from ns1 to IP2 will fail since it needs a (link layer) MAC address for delivering the packet. Hence the ARP request you see. ns2 does not respond to the ARP request for IP2 since it does not have IP2.
Manually adding an ARP entry for IP2 on ns1 allows to pass this link layer problem. On ns2 the packet from ns1 now can be observed.
But netcat will still does not show anything since it only expects packets on 0.0.0.0 - which means any IP address configured in ns2. Only, IP2 is not configured in ns2. Therefore, even if the packet got received on the link layer it gets not processed on the network layer (IP) - there simply is no IP address matching the destination of the packet.
Only once IP2 is added as IP for ns2 the network layer in ns2 feels responsible for it and delivers the payload to the application (nc).

Answering my own 3rd edit...
I don't know the REAL reason why the decision to reject UDP packets in that case was made, but I can think of a couple of reasons to do so:

Security: In cases like this one, chances are the IP address of the packet was spoofed, and that's usually only done with malicious intentions. DDoS, for instance.
It's pointless to do anything with it because you are supposed to establish some sort of communication between client and server and you can't do that because you can't answer. If you open 2 terminals and establish a UDP connection between the 2 with netcat, you will see that not only you can send UDP from client to server but also from server to client. This is how the UDP communication is supposed to be: 2 way, not just one way. If the communication can't be 2 way, why bother? Just send an error message and quit, it's hopeless.

